# localizar numeros string

Tags: java, string

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo un string tipo este:

```
String req="Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7 Ghz BOX";
String req2="Procesador AMD Ryzen 5 2600X 4.2 Ghz";
```

Lo que quiero es, extraer en un string la parte que pone "3.7 Ghz" y "4.2 Ghz". Estos son un par de ejemplos, por lo que no me sirve contar caracteres, ya que como veis van cambiando de posición. Lo que sí se mantiene siempre es que quiero sacar la misma cantidad de caracteres anteriores a Ghz...
¿Me podéis orientar en como hacerlo?

Lo unico que tengo es esto, pero no me sirve para este caso...

```
int fin = REQprocesador.indexOf("GHz", inicio + 1);
```

¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: Mete esto en una expresión regular: `\d\.\d GHZ`

Comment: como hago eso? Me puedes explicar como hacerlo, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

En Java con la clase Pattern y Matcher podemos hacer las validaciones y obtener los grupos de captura de la usando el método group de la clase Matcher:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\d\.\d GHZ");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7 Ghz BOX");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0)); 
            System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
            System.out.println(m.group(2)); 
            System.out.println(m.group(3)); 
        }
    }
```

Esto simplifica el extraer los valores de un cadena, de una manera menos frágil y más fácil de leer posteriormente el código fuente que usar la función split por uno o varios determinados caracteres, esta es una cadena bastante sencilla si el patrón es más complejo el código usando split puede complicarse notablemente. La clase Matcher contiene más métodos útiles, por ejemplo, con los métodos start y end nos es posible conocer la posición inicial y final de cada grupo de captura

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String req="Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7 Ghz BOX";
    String req2="Procesador AMD Ryzen 5 2600X 4.2 Ghz";

    System.out.println("Core 1: "+getCore(req));
    System.out.println("Core 2: "+getCore(req2));

}

private static String getCore(String req){
    //Se busca en el string el patrón Ghz
    int index = req.indexOf("Ghz");
    //Se realiza el substring de la palabra pasando como parametro la resta de 
    //4 a la variable anterior (son las posiciones delante de Ghz) y sumandole
    //3 (la longitud de Ghz).
    return req.substring(index-4, index+3);
}
```

Salida en consola:

```
Core 1: 3.7 Ghz
Core 2: 4.2 Ghz
```

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente como se haría en java pero lo voy a dejar en javascript y lo que tendrías que aplicar es la misma lógica en java..

1. Identificas la cadena
2. Lo separas por espacions
3. buscas el elemnto que contiene 'Ghz'
4. Y por ultimo lo une con el elemento anterior que contiene la cantidad

```js
var cadena = "Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7 Ghz BOX";
var elementos = cadena.split(" ");
for(a = 0; a <elementos.length; a++){
if(elementos[a] == 'Ghz'){
alert(elementos[a-1]+' '+elementos[a])
}
}
```

Ojala sea lo que buscas y te ayude con lo que necesitas.